How to send form-data with string and file in reactjs
 const addNews = async () => {
    let titleErrorText = "";
    let textErrorText = "";
    let imageErrorText = "";

    if (!title) {
      titleErrorText = "Введите загаловок";
    }

    if (!text) {
      textErrorText = "Введите описание";
    }

    if (!imagePath) {
      imageErrorText = "Загрузите изображение";
    }

    setTitleError(titleErrorText);
    setTextError(textErrorText);
    setImageError(imageErrorText);

    const dateObj = new Date(date);

    if (title && text && imagePath) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("title", title);
      formData.append("text", text);
      formData.append("date", dateObj.toISOString());
      formData.append("image", imagePath);

      console.log("FormData:", formData);

      try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

        const response = await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3000/files/uploads",
          formData,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );

        console.log("News added successfully:", response.data);
        setNewsList([...newsList, response.data]);

        setTitle("");
        setText("");
        setImagePath(null);
        setDate(new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0]);

        setTitleError("");
        setTextError("");
        setImageError("");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error adding news", error);
      }
    }
  };

This is my post-request. But when i delete img form-data and send it to backend, it returns me successfull sending. But when im trying to send form-data adding img too, i get 401 error. When im sending just like the string, same issue happens too
I tryed to change api's and got the 500 error
